# Which browser does not allow "remember me" option?

Tags: privacy, web-browser

As all the modern common browsers like IE, mozilla, chrome overrides the "autocomplete=off" feature and ask to remember the username/password, is there any not-so-popular modern browser which does not even ask the user to remember the user credentials?

Answer (score 4):

> As all the modern common browsers like IE, mozilla, chrome overrides
>   the "autocomplete=off" feature and ask to remember the
>   username/password,

Technically Chrome (and others) do not save for autocompletion; they save them to the password manager.  These are two different things and the latter is not proscribed by autocomplete=off.

In Chrome and Firefox the separation from autocompletion, and the use of a more sophisticated password manager, is clear.  In IE it's not; even though the passwords are stored in the Credentials Manager the option is still listed under "AutoComplete"... Caveat Microsoft :)

> is there any not-so-popular modern browser which does not even ask
>   the user to remember the user credentials?

I do not know of one, but if you don't like this behavior it's easy to turn off.

In Chrome:

- Go to Settings -> Advanced -> Passwords and Forms
- Uncheck "Offer to save your web passwords"

In Firefox:

- Go to Options -> Security
- Uncheck "Remember logins for sites"

In IE:

- Go to Internet Options -> Content
- Under AutoComplete, click Settings
- Uncheck "User names and passwords on forms"